# How to run a 32 bit JAVA Applet in 64 bit JRE MOC XOS

Tags: java, macos

I tried to change the 64 bit JRE to 32 bit JRE by dragging it under JavaPreferrence.app
But no use, it doesnt reflect....

Any answers/or focus on this issue plsss.

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't make much sense.

Basically, there is no such thing as a "32 bit Java applet".  A Java applet will run on either a 32 bit Java JVM or a 64 bit JVM.

And for the record, you cannot change a 32 bit JVM to a 64 bit JVM or vice-versa.  You will need to download the other flavor, and if it is not available then you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Stephen C,
But thing is that, I built an applet in 32 bit windows machine, and posted it on the server... 

When I hit the corresponding URL in 64 bit JVM MAC XOS SAFARI browser, it shows java Applet loading logo, later fails with an error, could not load applet.

Comment: That doesn't prove anything.  Have you looked at the Java console / logs to find out *why* the applet is not loading?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the applet in its own process via the JavaPreferrence.app

(Maybe the option is not there, depending on what Mac OS X version you are running.)